# Tank rigging and animations for Unity

Tags: animation, rigging, unity

I need some help on the workflow to create the rig and animations  in Blender for Unity.

I have a tank split in different objects (body, turret, cannon, wheels, track) and want to do some animations (move front, back, rotate, turret rotation, cannon recoil) in Blender to export all for Unity.

The problem is that, and I watched several tutorials and forum threads, I don't get how to properly animate the wheels and tracks.
I made a rig, but I can't rotate my wheels, just move all of them and the tracks.
I have seen that I could use drivers, but it seems that it is only for a Blender use.

What do I do?
Thank you ;)